# How to store data permanently in /tmp directory in linux

Tags: linux

Is there any way to store any data in Linux tmp directory. As i know Linux clear its /tmp directory when system is rebooted. But I want to store data permanently.

Comment: That seems to defeat the purpose of `/tmp`.

Comment: Why can't you store your data somewhere else?

Comment: That is exactly what tmp is made for! Store permanent data there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like [@bereal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647138/how-to-store-data-permanently-in-tmp-directory-in-linux/29647235#comment47434380_29647138) said, this defeats the purpose of the `/tmp` directory. Let me quote the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES):

> The /tmp directory must be made available for programs that require temporary files.
>
> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program.

You'll find a better place to store permanent data.

Comment: The better place is often under `/var`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's linux you are free to do what you want to do (as root). When /tmp is cleared depends on your system and can be changed; there is no particular magic involved. A good summary seems to be here: https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared.

Of course if you are root you can set up an entirely different global directory, say "/not-quite-tmp" or such. But I assume that some progs not under your control write to tmp and you want to inspect or in any case persist those files.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to do wrong things, it’s still possible.

`/tmp` directory is cleared accordigly to `TMPTIME` setting. The default is apparently `0`, what means “clear on every startup”.

The value might be changed in `/etc/default/rcS` (value is to be set in days.)